# Angular CLI - How to resolve url in CSS or SCSS?

Tags: url, angular-cli

I have a component whose SCSS references an image in the same component folder, using `background-image: url('./logo.jpg')`.

Removing the leading ./ does not help either. In any case, the image does not show in the browser.

I am running `ng serve` and looking at the `dist` folder, logo.jpg is indeed copied and placed in the same component folder as expected.

I would also like to be able to reference images from other locations outside the folder that my .css or .scss file lives in, using relative paths like I do with my component .html and .css from the .ts file.

I think I need some sort of url resolver that would generate the full URL on the outputted .css file. How would I obtain such a resolver and how do I configure it in Angular CLI?

Answer (score 13):

Had the same problem. Solved it by changing the path in the Less/Sass file to `url(/assets/path_to_img)` and it should work. Don't forget the "`/`" at the beginning and to put your image in the assets folder.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a similar behavior.

It seems that images referenced in the CSS under the Assets folder are extracted and given a guid, whereas the same does not apply to Component level CSS.

In the end I copied the image file under the Assets folder (without referencing it in Angular-cli.json) and then I was able to reference it in the component CSS with:

background: url(assets/img/bgs/footer.png);

Answer (score 0):

try using this  background-image: url("./~/assets/images/artist-bg.jpg");